# What is better thing among store data into xml file or into a database in Android?

Tags: android, xml, web-services, sqlite

I'm new in Android world, I'm developing an app that gather data from an WebService that responds me with a xml file and I need to store it into a structure where I can access it in a easy way.
What do you suggest me to use? I thought about using a new xml file or a SQLite database on Android. I need the easiest and safest way to do that.
Please help me! 
I'll appreciate very much a easy guide if exist!
Thank to everybody

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: I need to enquire into different information that I'll use to show to the user. I suppose, the amount of data is going to be a lot! I mean, the webservice doesn't give me the information I need to, it gives me some data that if  put together it means something different for me. I hope I explained good what I need. I can't use webservice's data directly, I have to store them and then when I've got all the data, I can ask for different information linked between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is use SQLite database since Relational databases are better for handling large volumes of data within a system. They have mature management systems that can efficiently and reliably maintain large quantities of structured data. This data can be updated via transactions that ensure the integrity of the database and the content can be extracted very quickly when properly configured. There is no equivalent XML management system, and using XML documents directly for storing and maintaining large volumes of data can prove both inefficient and unreliable.